# IE9 freezes with Protected Mode enabled

Tags: internet-explorer-9, protected-mode

After a disk failure and a new build of Win7, IE9 locks up on most web pages including Bing. Running it as Admin works, and turning off Protected Mode also works. Neither of these was necessary prior to the rebuild and examination of colleagues' workstation config show that it's only my workstation with this quirk.

Can anyone suggest a remedy? I have tried `bcdedit /set {current} nx AlwaysOff` and a reboot, with no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had same IE9 browser issue as described by Peter, but on an otherwise normally-funtioning Win7/64 PC (IE not a Win7 rebuild as Peter described). Thinking about what was common to the web sites I could not get to, plugins hit my mind, Flash in particular: I uninstalling and reinstalled Flash and Shockwave, which have recent update releases, and that corrected the issue allowing browsing to various sites (EG BBC.com) with the "Enable Protected Mode" box checked as it ideally should be.

Whether it matters I don't know, but I did the reinstall under the domain user's account by entering the domain admin u/p when prompted.

I also did not isolate whether it was actually Flash, Shockwave, or both, that caused the initial issue.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem, even though I uninstalled Flash it didn't fully uninstall:

[Uninstall Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html)

Comment: Did the OP say that Flash was the problem? This may be helpful, and then again it may not.

Comment: It could be this, I'll have to check. Flash is certainly present. I'm off sick today but I will give this a whirl tomorrow. Adobe is high on my most-unwanted list :)